# Can we use EASession object's inputstream property to send data to a bluetooth Headset in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, audio-streaming

Can we send a recorded audio stream to the bluetooth Headset input, using the EASession object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The External Accessory framework is used for connecting with devices that comply with the Made for iPod Program and that define their own data communication protocol.  You are not given access to the standard Bluetooth communication stack for dealing with audio devices or the like.

Comment: Hi Thanks Brad. Is it at least possible for me to record a audio and play it live? (I assume if the user wears a Bluetooth headset the Audio would be played through the Headset)

Comment: @Krishnan - Sure, if you have access to the original audio stream you should be able to buffer it for playback across the standard audio output, which would go to any supported headphones.

Comment: Brad, can we do the recording and playback simultaneously in such a way that user is able to hear instantly every noise that occurs outside?

Comment: @Krishnan - Again, if you have access to the audio from the microphone, you should be able to feed that through your audio out stream.  So yes, this should be possible.